# What's the number of bijections between two finite sets with certain conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a problem and I need some help :)

Assume $ \mathbb{N}\ni n \ge 3$ and  consider a bijection $f:[n] \to [n]$ such that: $f(1)=1,f(2)=3,\forall 1<i: f(i)\ne i$.

**The question is**:

How many different functions $f$ (as mentioned above) are there?

**What I tried**:

There is only one option for $f(1)$ which is $1$.
Same for $f(2)=3$.

Now we need to decide $f(x)$   for $ x
\in \{ 3,4,5,\dots ,n-1,n\}$. But here is where I get confused. If we're looking at $x=3$ then there are $(n-2)$ options for $f(3)$, the options are the elements of the set $\{ 2,4,5,\dots ,n-1,n\}$. But if I try to do that for $x\ne3 $ for example $x=4$, then there are $(n-3)$ options. For each case I need to repeat this process, so it doesn't seem like the right way to approach this problem.

So, I tried to look at the set of bijections $f:[n] \to [n]$ ($n \ge 3$) s.t: $f(1)=1 , \forall 1<i: f(i)\ne i$. I tried to "count" how many elements there are in this set, but I don't know how to answer it also.

I would appreciate it if you could help me solve my questions and maybe explain how to think about it.

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements

Comment: these are the derangements on $\{2, \cdots, n\}$ which take $2$ to $3$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. How can I know how many derangements on $\{2,\dots ,n\}$ which take 2 to 3 there are?

Comment: @AnuragA thank you for your comment.

Comment: Hint:  there's nothing special about $3$.  The answer would be the same if $f(2)$ were $4$ or $5$ etc.

Comment: @lulu thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you want the number of derangements $f$ of the set $\{2,3,\dots,n\}$ such that $f(2)=3$. The answer is
$$\frac{D_{n-1}}{n-2}$$
since there are $D_{n-1}$ derangements of $\{2,3,\dots,n\}$, and there are $n-2$ equally likely values for $f(2)$ in such a derangement.

Comment: This is a nice symmetry argument.

Comment: After posting this answer, I noticed that the same argument had already been suggested in a comment by lulu.

Comment: I recognized that after reading your answer.

Comment: @bof First of all, thank you so much. Second, why the fact that:
"there are $n-2$ equally likely values for $f(2)$" means you can devide $D_{n-1}$ by $n-2$  and get the right answer?

Comment: @Lior There are $D_{n - 1}$ derangements of $\{2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.  If there were no restrictions, there would be $n - 2$ possible images for $2$.  The restriction that $f(2) = 3$ means only one of these $n - 2$ images is possible.  Therefore, we must divide $D_{n - 1}$ by $n - 2$ to account for the restriction that $f(2) = 3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I understand all of what you meantioned. But still don't get why dividing gives me what I'm looking for. I think it's something more basic that I don't understand.

Comment: @Lior As lulu stated in the comments, we would get the same number of bijections if $f(2) = 3$ as if $f(2) = 4$ or $f(2) = 5$ or $\ldots$ $f(2) = n$.  Therefore, if $a_n$ is the number of bijections with the property that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 3$, then $(n - 2)a_n = D_{n - 1}$ since are $a_n$ bijections for each of the $n - 2$ choices for $f(2)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146251/discussion-between-lior-and-n-f-taussig).

Comment: If $x_i$ is the number of derangements $f$ with $f(2)=i$ then the total number of derangements is $D_{n-1}=x_3+x_4+\cdots+x_n$. Since $x_3=x_4=\cdots=x_n$ it follows that $D_{n-1}=(n-2)x_3$, so $x_3=D_{n-1}/(n-2)$. @Lior

Comment: @bof thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Consider cases, depending on whether or not $f(3) = 2$.

If $f(3) = 2$, then the requirement that $f(i) \neq i$ means we must have a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) on the remaining $n - 3$ elements in the set $[n]$.

If $f(3) \neq 2$, then each of the $n - 2$ elements in $[n]$ greater than $2$ have one prohibited image.  For $3$, the prohibited image is $2$; for each $i > 3$, the prohibited image is $i$.  The number of bijections of $n - 2$ elements in which each element in the domain has  exactly one unique prohibited image is equal to the number of derangements of $n - 2$ objects.

Hence, the number of bijections $f: [n] \to [n]$ such that $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 3$, and $f(i) \neq i$ for each $i > 1$ is
$$a_n = D_{n - 3} + D_{n - 2}$$

Notice that our formula yields
$$a_3 = D_0 + D_1 = 1 + 0 = 1$$
which is true since the only possible bijection that satisfies the requirements is $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 2$.

Similarly, our formula yields
$$a_4 = D_1 + D_2 = 0 + 1 = 1$$
which is true since the only possible bijection that satisfies the requirements is $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 4, f(4) = 2$.

Our formula yields
$$a_5 = D_2 + D_3 = 1 + 2 = 3$$
which is true since there are three bijections that satisfy the requirements.

$$
\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
k & f_k(1) & f_k(2) & f_k(3) & f_k(4) & f_k(5)\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 4\\
2 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}
$$
Notice that there is $D_2 = 1$ bijection that maps $3$ to $2$ and $D_3 = 2$ bijections that do not map $3$ to $2$.

Comment: Can you explain the $f(3) \neq 2$ case better? Is "have one prohibited position" sufficient to result in $D_{n-2}$? $\quad$ For example, if $ f(1) \neq 1, f(2) \neq 1, f(3) \neq 2$, then we could have $(2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 1)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Keep in mind that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(2) = 3$ are both required to be true.  If $f(3) \neq 2$, then each of the $n - 2$ terms other than $1$ and $2$ have one prohibited position.  For $3$, the prohibited image is $2$.  For each $i > 3$, the prohibited image is $i$.  I will add this to my answer in a moment.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how your way works. EG Which are the $n-2$ values that we are deranging? Note also that $f(3) \neq 3$ so there are 2 prohibited positions for 3. $\quad$        The way I've seen this done, is to define $g(2) = f(3) \neq 2$, $g(i) = f(i)$ for $i = 4, 5, \ldots n$, and then show that $g$ is a dernagement on the $n-2$ values of $2, 3, 4, \ldots n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin We are deranging the $n - 2$ values $3, 4, 5, \ldots, n$.  The values of $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ are fixed.  Since $f$ is a permutation, $3$ is not a possible image for $3$, which would ordinarily free $3$ to go anywhere.  By placing the additional restriction that $f(3) \neq 2$, there is now one prohibited image for $3$, namely that it cannot be mapped to $2$.  For each $i > 3$, we have the restriction that $f(i) \neq i$.  Thus, for each $i \geq 3$, there is one prohibited image.

Comment: @CalvinLin Notice that the face $f(3) \ne 3$ means nothing to you in matter of possible positions, because it's taken ( $f(2)=3$ ). So, basically there is only one prohibited position for $x=3$ which is $2$. Why? because we're on the case which $f(3) \ne 2$. So, you want to map $3$ to $\{4,5,\dots,n\}$ and you want to map $ x \in \{ 4, \dots ,n\}$ to  $ \{ 2,4,\dots ,n\} \setminus \{x\}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Notice $| \{4,5,\dots,n\} |=n-3$ , $ |  \{ 2,4,\dots ,n\} \setminus \{x\} |=n-3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I understand this answer. Thanks for expalining. I'm trying to understand the other answer now :)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's not quite true that you're deranging the $n-2$ values $3, 4, ... n$, because you have some $f(i) = 2$ (And also, having $f(3) \neq 2$ isn't really a restriction since 2 isn't in your derangement domain). $\quad$ You can get around those issues with the definition of $g$, that allows for the clean derangement on $2, 4, 5, \ldots, n$ (sorry for the typo).

Comment: @Lior In the $f(3) \neq 2$ case, the number of solutions is derangement on $n-2$ values, not $n-3$ or $n-1$. We currently have $ f: \{ 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, n \} \rightarrow \{ 2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots, n \}$, which appears to be a derangement on $n-1$ values, but with $f(2) = 3$, and it's not clear why it's $D_{n-2}$. $\quad$      With the definition of $g$ ($g(2) = f(3), g(i) = f(i)$), we have a derangement on $ \{ 2, 4, 5, \ldots, n \}$ to establish the bijection to $D_{n-2}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin I see your point about the wording.  However, when $f(3) \neq 2$, there is one prohibited image for each of the $n - 2$ values $3, 4, \ldots, n$ in the domain, which is why there are $D_{n - 2}$ ways to arrange the images so that $f(i) \neq i$.

Comment: But your domain and range are not identical, so talking about a derangement makes no sense to me. $\quad$ I have stated my point, and I think you've gotten it, so I'm not going to belabor it further. While I think there's a slight gap in your explanation (which can be fixed), since OP doesn't seem to think so, I will defer to them.

Comment: @CalvinLin  I rewrote the third paragraph to emphasize that the number of bijections on $n - 2$ elements in which each element in the domain has exactly one prohibited image is equal to the number of derangements on $n - 2$ objects.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, if $f: \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \rightarrow \{ 4, 5, 6 \}$ with $f(1) \neq 4, f(2) \neq 4, f(3) \neq 4$ satisfies the "each element in the domain has exactly one prohibited image ", then there are $2^3 = 8 $ solutions, not $ D_1 = 1$.  So again, something is missing in the logic. Perhaps you also want "exactly one unique prohibited image", in which case yes we can set up the bijection (and hence equivalent to what I was saying about creating $g$).